# TypeScript compilation extremely slow > 12s

Tags: performance, typescript, angular, webpack

Just putting this out there to see if someone else is having this issue...

I have building an angular 2 app with typescript using webpack as my build tool, it all works well, however I have noticed typescript compilation is super super slow, I am at 12 seconds right now...., and its pretty clear that is all due to the typescript compilation process....

I have used ts-loader or awesome-typescript-loader with a similar result, if I comment out this loader, my build time drops to around 1 sec....

After some research it seems like its 'normal' to have 'slow' times when compiling typescript, but is 12secs the normal??

Old posts hinted it might be due to a node version conflict, I am currently running v4.4.2...

Any how below is my webpack code in case anyone spots something wrong there.. the commented code in the Uglify section is due to some 'bug' on the angular 2 side...

```
const path = require('path');
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const webpack = require('webpack');

const NpmInstallPlugin = require('npm-install-webpack-plugin');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const TARGET = process.env.npm_lifecycle_event;

const PATHS = {
  app: path.join(__dirname, 'app'),
  dist: path.join(__dirname, 'dist')
};

const common = {
  entry: {
    vendor: ['./app/vendor.ts'],
    main: ['./app/boot.component.ts']
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name].[hash].bundle.js',
    path: PATHS.dist
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.ts']
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      title: 'Qarrot Performance',
      template: 'index.template.ejs',
      commonStyles: [
        '/public/styles/vendor/normalize.css',
        '/public/styles/main.css'
      ],
      commonScripts: [],
      baseHref: '/',
      unsupportedBrowser: true,
      mobile: true,
      appMountId: 'app'
    }),
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loaders: ['ts-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loader: 'raw-loader!sass-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        loader: "html"
      }
    ]
  }
}

// Dev Settings
if(TARGET === 'start' || !TARGET) {
  module.exports = merge(common, {
    devtool: 'eval-source-map',
    devServer: {
      contentBase: PATHS.build,
      historyApiFallback: true,
      hot: true,
      inline: true,
      progress: true,
      stats: 'errors-only',
    },
    plugins: [
      new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
      new NpmInstallPlugin({
        save: true
      })
    ]
  });
}

// Prod Settings
if(TARGET === 'build') {
  module.exports = merge(common, {
    devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map',
    plugins: [
      // new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      //   beautify: false,
      //   mangle: false,
      //   compress : { screw_ie8 : true },
      //   comments: false
      // }),
      new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
      new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'process.env.NODE_ENV': '"production"'
      }),
      new CopyWebpackPlugin([
            { from: 'public', to: 'public' }
      ]),
      new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
        names: ['vendor', 'manifest']
      }),
    ]
  });
}
```

I am also on a Mac, running Angular 2 beta.15 and webpack version 1.12, below is my tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  },
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings/main",
    "typings/main.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I would stick to the `awesome-typescript-loader`.  It has some performance options you can enable: a caching option and a transpile only option:

```
"awesomeTypescriptLoaderOptions": {
  "useCache": true,
  "transpileOnly": true
}
```

Both of these had a significant improvement on compile times.

Answer (score 0):

There is now [an official wiki](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Performance) suggesting best practices and ways to troubleshoot compiler performance. It's pages long, so there's lots of information to help. Here's one of many suggestions:

> ### `extendedDiagnostics`
>
> You can run TypeScript with `--extendedDiagnostics` to get a printout of where the compiler is spending its time.
>
> ```
> Files:                         6
> Lines:                     24906
> Nodes:                    112200
> Identifiers:               41097
> Symbols:                   27972
> Types:                      8298
> Memory used:              77984K
> Assignability cache size:  33123
> Identity cache size:           2
> Subtype cache size:            0
> I/O Read time:             0.01s
> Parse time:                0.44s
> Program time:              0.45s
> Bind time:                 0.21s
> Check time:                1.07s
> transformTime time:        0.01s
> commentTime time:          0.00s
> I/O Write time:            0.00s
> printTime time:            0.01s
> Emit time:                 0.01s
> Total time:                1.75s
> ```
>
> > Note that `Total time` won't be the sum of all times preceding it, since there is some overlap and some work is not instrumented.
>
> The most relevant information for most users is:
>
> | Field | Meaning |
> | --- | --- |
> | `Files` | the number of files that the program is including (use `--listFilesOnly` to see what they are). |
> | `I/O Read time` | time spent reading from the file system - this includes traversing `include`'d folders. |
> | `Parse time` | time spent scanning and parsing the program |
> | `Program time` | combined time spent performing reading from the file system, scanning and parsing the program, and other calculation of the program graph. These steps are intermingled and combined here because files need to be resolved and loaded once they're included via `import`s and `export`s. |
> | `Bind time` | Time spent building up various semantic information that is local to a single file. |
> | `Check time` | Time spent type-checking the program. |
> | `transformTime time` | Time spent rewriting TypeScript ASTs (trees that represent source files) into forms that work in older runtimes. |
> | `commentTime` | Time spent calculating comments in output files. |
> | `I/O Write time` | Time spent writing/updating files on disk. |
> | `printTime` | Time spent calculating the string representation of an output file and emitting it to disk. |
>
> Things that you might want to ask given this input:
>
> - Does the number of files/number of lines of code roughly correspond to the number of files in your project? Try running `--listFiles` if not.
> - Does `Program time` or `I/O Read time` seem fairly high? Ensure your `include`/`exclude` settings are configured correctly.
> - Do other times seem off? You might want to file an issue! Things you can do to help diagnose it might be
>
>   - Running with `emitDeclarationOnly` if `printTime` is high.
>   - Read up instructions on Reporting Compiler Performance Issues.

Answer (score -1):

Please share you `tsconfig.json`. Most likely you have `noEmitOnError` set to `true` which means that the compiler is *forced to typecheck the whole codebase* before any emitting.

Please set that to false.

Comment: Hey @basart thanks for your suggestion, I have updated my question with my tsconfig... I did not have that option set, but it did not have much of an impact when I added it though...